# Calculate numerical features over time having the origin and evolutions over time

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have 2 input dataframes :

- One is the origin of some numerical features
- Second is the evolutions of that features over time

```
origin <- data.frame("year"=2017,"a"=5,"b"=2)
evolutions <- data.frame("year"=c(2018,2019,2020),"a"=c(1.2,1.5,2),"b"=c(0.5,2,2))
```

What I need is to recover the values of the numerical features for each period

```
output <- data.frame("year"=c(2017,2018,2019,2020),"a"=c(5,6,9,18),"b"=c(2,1,2,4))
```

Seems simple, I basically need to multiply the origin by the evolutions step by step. However, I can't find an efficient way to do this : currently I am looping with a for loop but I am not satisfied with this.
Any idea ? Any package solution (`dplyr`, `data.table` or even `base`) would be great.

Thank you !

Comment: Is the origin data frame has more rows (for 2018, 2019 and so on). If not I don't understand the logic behind your output

Comment: Seems like you want `cumprod`, e.g. `cumprod(c(origin$a, evolutions$a))`

Comment: Thank you very much, that exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the proposition of @Henrik in the comments, here is a solution, with a loop on colnames, assuming date is at the first position and the two inputs share the same colnames :

```
output <- data.frame("year" = c(origin$year, evolutions$year),
                     sapply(colnames(origin)[-1], function(x) cumprod(c(origin[[x]], evolutions[[x]]))))
```